# How to handle multi-select in drop down (jquery mobile)?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu, multi-select

In the below jquery mobile html code, onchange function (onchangeInDropDown();) is called whenever there is a change in multi-select option in drop down. I'm doing some time consuming operation (updating the UI, based on item selected) whenever there is a change. I'm seeing some strange behaviour if I select more than one options quickly (one after another). Could you please suggest me a better way to handle this.

Thought of implementing the following solution, but do not know how to implement it.

Removing the onchange function and put the OK button in the overlay menu. On selecting the OK button, will call a function to get all the item selected and update the UI with respect to the item selected, ie., update all together instead of every change. The problem here is I do not know how to put OK button in the overlay menu. Is there a way to put ok button in overlay menu

Please help me!!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> Multiselect item </title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- below three tags , link and script are for showing pop up toast dialogs -->
  <link href="css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/toastr.js"></script>
  <link href="css/toastr-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.jsPlumb-1.4.1-all-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function onchangeInDropDown (){
    //Performing some time consuming operation and updating the ui based on item selected
}

function getDropDownValue() {

    var inputElems = document.getElementById("item_drop_select");
    count = 0;

for (var i=1; i<inputElems.length; i++) {
    if (inputElems[i].selected == true) {
        count++;
        alert (inputElems[i].value);
        // Update the UI based on item inputElems[i].value
    }
}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="myform">
<div id="item_drop" class="ui-screen-hidden" style="display: block" >

<select data-mini="true" id="item_drop_select" name="item_drop_select" size="1" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" onchange="onchangeInDropDown();">
  <option >Multi-select list of item to buy</option>
  <option value="milk" id="milk" >Milk</option>
  <option value="oil" id="oil" >Oil</option>
  <option value="rice" id="rice" >Rice</option>
  <option value="softdrinks" id="softdrinks" >Softdrinks</option>
  <option value="detergent" id="detergent" >Detergent</option>
</select> 

<div data-role="button" id= "goButton" style= "visibility:block" onclick="getDropDownValue();">Get the drop down values </div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please replace this data-native-menu="true". It will open Select menu as native control.